# how to verify if the url exist not redirecting?

Tags: python

how to verify if the page url exist and not redirect to not found url page 
example :

```
import socket
try:
    socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com/imghp')
except socket.gaierror as ex:
    print "Not existe"
```

it retourn alwayse **Not existe**

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  `socket.gethostbyname` doesn't take a URL.  Probably  you want to make an HTTP request, which is a totally different API.

Comment: `gethostbyname()` can be uses with a host name not with a (incomplete) URL. Try `gethostbyname('www.google.com')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### you're using the wrong tool for the task!

[image: screw hammer]

From the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname):

> **socket.gethostbyname(hostname)**
>
> Translate a host name to IPv4 address format. The IPv4 address is returned as a string, such as '100.50.200.5'. If the host name is an IPv4 address itself it is returned unchanged. See gethostbyname_ex() for a more complete interface. gethostbyname() does not support IPv6 name resolution, and getaddrinfo() should be used instead for IPv4/v6 dual stack support.

That tool is to check if a *domain* exists, and get its IP address:

```
>>> try:
...     print(socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com'))
... except socket.gaierror as ex:
...     print("Does not exists")
... 
216.58.211.132
```

what you may want is to actually connect to the site and check if there's a page:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.head('http://www.google.com/imghp')
>>> if response.status_code == 404:
...    print("Does not exists")
... else:
...    print("Exists")
...
Exists
```

The [`.head()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=head#requests.head) method from [python-requests](/questions/tagged/python-requests) only gets the information about the page from the webserver, but not the page itself, so it's very lightweight in terms of network usage.

*spoiler alert*: if you try to get the contents of the page, using [`response.content`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=content#requests.Response.content), you'll get nothing, for that you need to use the [`.get()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=get#requests.get) method.

---

#### update #1

the site you're checking against is broken, i.e. it does not follow internet standards. Instead of giving a `404`, it's giving a `302` to redirect to the "page does not exists" page with a status code of `200`:

```
>>> response = requests.head('http://qamarsoft.com/does_not_exists', allow_redirects=True)
>>> response.status_code
200
```

To sort that out, you need to get the page of that site, and check that the redirected URI has `404` in the redirection URL:

```
>>> response = requests.head('http://qamarsoft.com/does_not_exists'
>>> response.headers['location']
'http://qamarsoft.com/404'
```

So the test would become:

```
>>> response = requests.head('http://qamarsoft.com/does_not_exists')
>>> if '404' in response.headers['location']:
...     print('Does not exists')
... else:
...     print('Exists')
Exists
```

---

#### update #2

for the second URL, you can try it out yourself in the python console:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.head('http://www.***********.ma/does_not_Exists')
>>> if response.status_code == 404:
...    print("Does not exists")
... else:
...    print("Exists")
...
Does not exists
>>> response = requests.head('http://www.***********.ma/annonceur/a/3550/n.php ')
>>> if response.status_code == 404:
...    print("Does not exists")
... else:
...    print("Exists")
...
Exists
```

---

#### Nota Bene

you might want to install the `requests` package:

```
pip install requests
```

or if you're modern and use python3:

```
pip3 install requests
```

Comment: try using your code with the page [link]http://www.qamarsoft.com/HttpUrlDontExist[/link] **will return Exists** !!!

Comment: because it outputs a `302` code to get to a `404` page, which in turn gives a `200` status code. The given site is broken, not my code! :-)

Comment: thanks brother using you're first post with a test on 200 response

Comment: Well, don't miss all the other status errors, like `500`, `503`, `403` etc… As for the second site you gave, you wanted to the existence of a page on a site that does not respects Internet standards. All in all, you might have a **valid** page that does a `302 Redirect` code, followed by a `200 OK` code, while the other one you gave gives the same but truly is a `404`.

Comment: can you just delete the  second url of test plz

Comment: I can and just did, but it's never going to be totally removed, as [all changes](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28926436/revisions) are versioned and available publicly. Sorry for your site to stay in posterity as not respecting Internet standards ;-)

Comment: I'm talking about the second url that one telecon.* not the qamarso.* plz

Comment: done, but know that it's still public, as published on [the revision 4](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28926436/4) page, that cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that with `gethostbyname()` you will not get what you want done. Consider using `urllib2`. In your case the following could do what you want:

```
import urllib2

#The data variable can be used to send POST data
data=None
#Here add as many header fields as you wish
headers={"User-agent":"Blahblah", "Cookie":"yourcookievalues"}
url = "http://www.google.com/imghp"
request = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    #Check redirection here
    if (response.geturl() != url):
         print "The page at: "+url+" redirected to: "+response.geturl()
except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
    #Catch 404s etc.
    print "Failed with code: "+str(err)
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Comment: anyway, [tag:python-requests] does the same thing, but in less lines!

Comment: @zmo well yeah, but if you take out my comments, blank lines and the variable declaration and just pass them directly to the function, like you did, then it's pretty much the same.

Comment: your code is equivalent to: `print("Exists" if requests.head(URL, allow_redirects=True).status_code != 404 else "Not Exists")`, no need for the try block and the redirect check. There's a good reason why [tag:python-requests] rocks :-)